# Refreshing Data Automatically in Interactive Grid, Reflow Report

Tags: oracle-apex, oraclereports

I want to refresh data automatically in interactive grid ,reflow report. I tried this method it worked for classic and interactive report:

I wrote static I’d for classic “ATTENDANCE”
And static I’d for interactive report “INTER”
and write this code in JavaScript in execute when page load :

```js
Setinterval(“jquery(“#ATTENDANCE”).trigger(‘apexrefresh’);”10000);
Setinterval(“jquery(“#INTER”).trigger(‘apexrefresh’);”10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setInterval(function () {apex.region("ATTENDANCE").refresh()}, 10000);` instead of the jquery refresh

Comment: I tried this one but it doesn’t work